# Android: onPrepareDialogBuilder, onClick & setItemChecked

Tags: android, android-preferences

I've spent over a week trying to figure out a way to do a Limited Multi Selection Preference list. Nothing I've tried works. I'm ready to give up on Android if something seemingly simple is so hard. I've been programming a long time and don't remember being beaten up this badly by something like this. I have to assume I am not understanding something basic. I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Here is the simplest code I can think off that should work. It does not clear the checkbox even when setting it to false, I've tried true as well. Why doesn't that work? If that will not work, what will?

Any help would be most appreciated.

```
    @Override
    protected void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder) 
    {
     CharSequence[] entries = getEntries();
     CharSequence[] entryValues = getEntryValues();

        if (entries == null || entryValues == null || entries.length != entryValues.length ) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
                    "ListPreference requires an entries array and an entryValues array which are both the same length");
        }

        // Added by WJT since we are loading the entries values after instantiation 
        // we need the clicked indexes to be setup now, they would not have been
        // set up in the constructor
        if ((mClickedDialogEntryIndices == null) || (mClickedDialogEntryIndices.length == 0))
         mClickedDialogEntryIndices = new boolean[getEntries().length];

        restoreCheckedEntries();
        builder.setMultiChoiceItems(entries, mClickedDialogEntryIndices, 
                new DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() 
        {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean val) 
   {
    mDlg = (AlertDialog)getDialog();
                mListView = (ListView)mDlg.getListView();
    if (val)
             {
              if (mSelectedCount < mLimit)
                 {
               mClickedDialogEntryIndices[which] = val;
                  mSelectedCount++;

                 }
              else
                 {
                  mListView.setItemChecked(which, false);
               Toast.makeText(getContext(),
              R.string.newsLimitExceededMessage,
              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }  // (mSelectedCount < mLimit)

             }
             else
             {
              mClickedDialogEntryIndices[which] = val;
              mSelectedCount--;

             }  // (val)

   }  // void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which, boolean val)


        });  //  DialogInterface.OnMultiChoiceClickListener() 

    }  // void onPrepareDialogBuilder(Builder builder)
```

Thanks,

\ ^ / i l l

Comment: What, precisely, is "a Limited Multi Selection Preference list"? What, specifically, is not working? What is your expected behavior? Have you considered using a `Dialog`-themed `Activity`, where you have a lot more flexibility?

Comment: @CommonsWare: What I am trying to accomplish is a preference option that allows a user to select multiple items from a pre defined list. I want to limit how many of those items are selected. My preference would be to disable all non selected items once the limit is reached leaving the selected items enabled. I would settle for unchecking each check box over the limit with a message to the user.

Comment: @CommonsWare: I tried building a ListView that would perform the main portion of this with no success once I tried to attach it to the Preferences sub system. That is as close as I've gottent to a separate Activity. 

In the code above I'm simply trying to uncheck a checkbox that exceeds the preset limit of checkboxes allowed. It does not uncheck the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I would approach the problem:

Step #1: Get this working in a standalone throwaway test activity. Forget preferences. Forget dialogs. Just focus on the functionality of having a `CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE` `ListView` where, after a certain number of items are checked, the unchecked items become disabled.

Step #2: Get the functionality from Step #1 working in the form of a custom widget. By this, I mean you would implement a subclass of `ListView` (I guess...might be some container if there's more to it than a `ListView`) that bakes in all of what you need from Step #1.

Step #3: Create a custom `DialogPreference` subclass that uses the custom widget from Step #2.

For example, [here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-colormixer) where I have a custom `ColorMixer` widget, rolled into a `ColorPreference`.

Comment: Thanks, at one point I started with your Color Mixer sample. I'll go back to something like that and see if I have more success. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Thanks for helping me settle down on this and start over. Following your steps helped me get to the point where I have it working. It is not perfect but it is working and for now that is good enough. :)